# Does visual studio keep track of where your program crashed?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So my program crashed in a demo and I want to know where it crashed. I was wondering if visual studio saves that somewhere.

Comment: That would be down to you. Usual way is a top level exception trap and log the exception and stack trace to a file, which you can then peruse at your leisure. If you've got nothing like that. That would be nothing to do with VS though, were you demoing from Visual Studio??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Visual Studio debugger attached, during the debug session it can stop on any uncaught exceptions.  There's also the IntelliTrace window in the higher SKUs of VS that will show a log of any tracing activity, including when exceptions were thrown and caught.

If the debugger wasn't attached (or VS wasn't running), then there's nothing AFAIK to keep a record.  However most app crashes will get logged to the Windows Event Log, and usually include a stack trace.  Launch the Event Viewer, and look under Windows Logs -> Application.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically, unless you have your own logging enabled (such as log4net). If you're lucky you may find something in the Windows Event Log. But Visual Studio - nope.